# Split tasks into two pages

Tags: inno-setup

I have an Inno Setup installer with a Tasks list which has gotten quite big mainly due to a few radio button choice lists. Is there any known way to split the Tasks list's options into two pages, instead of making it scroll?

All of the options involved are basically configuration settings of the installed program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really have that many (one off) tasks? Splitting the page can not be done automatically by Inno. If you want them split, you will need to use a custom dialog and use `Check:` parameters on the conditional entries.
An alternive is to use components that is a more explicit "list of things being installed" rather than a "list of things to do".

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid it would be like that. My problem is, it's really only 4 options. But 2 of them are radio button choices (one of 3 and one of 4 items). Those fill up the page REALLY fast. I'm not really familiar with putting options in custom pages and checking them, though, do you have any more information on that?

Comment: Again, it sounds like you're misusing `[Tasks]`. Are you sure they aren't `[Components]`? I can't provide a sample that does exactly what you want, but check out the CodeDlg.iss example installed with Inno.

Comment: Nope, they're all settings for configuring the game. Stuff like language choice, game resolution, etc. I've decided to leave off most of them and just give the option to launch the program's config tool after installation though.

Comment: So, yes they are being misused. a `[Task]` is something to do as a one of, rather than a state that is preserved or set. An alternative is a custom page.